# Nim import from project root directory

Tags: nim-lang

How to import a module from project root directory in Nim?

Instead of doing so:

```py
import ../../http
import ../seq
```

I'd like to import my module using absolute path relative to the project root directory, like this:

```py
import src/http
import src/utils/seq
```

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done by giving nim the project root directory as a new search path:

```
nim c --path:'.' project.nim
```

And you can drop in a `config.nims` at the project root with the content `--path:"."` to automate this.

So, with a directory tree like

```
.
├── config.nims
├── project.nim
└── src
    ├── http.nim
    └── utils
        ├── dir
        │   └── editing_me.nim
        └── seq.nim
```

The `editing_me.nim` module can then import http and seq as
`src/http` and `src/utils/seq`. You will still be able to import them with relative paths, too.

Comment: Read more about config: [NimScript](https://nim-lang.org/docs/nims.html), the options in [Compiler User Guide](https://nim-lang.org/docs/nimc.html#compiler-usage)

Comment: Did not know that flag this is neat! Thx